# Curl with ipv6 not working by default

Tags: ipv6, https, curl

I am trying to curl ipv6 adresses, but without success.

If i try lets say:

> curl https://google.com

I wait for a timeout and get `network unreachable`

If i force `ipv4`, everything is fine.

> curl -4 https://google.com

Then again if i force ipv6, like this:

> curl -6 https://google.com

i get:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2800:3f0:4001:806::1005: Network is unreachable

I suppose it has to do somehow with resolving `ipv6` adresses.

I saw that on other computers that have a newer version of some linux distro, these requests go fine, so i'm guessing it has to do something with me using `ubuntu 10.10`, where this problem isn't solved.

I want to be able to curl normally without using the option: `-4`, what do i have to modify to be able to use curl normally with `ipv6` adresses?

Comment: If you know that the problem is with Ubuntu 10.10 you should upgrade. Hacky ways to solve it and/or workarounds are just not worth the time and effort if you could do something more simple as upgrading.

Comment: @guntbert is not a dupe but off-topic. He doesn't ask how to upgrade his system, but how to fix the obsolete curl.

Comment: You may want to disable ipv6 on your nic: `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf=0` or `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0`.

Comment: I've edited this to reflect that it is still not working  as of Ubuntu 14.04, which is not end-of-life.  No longer off-topic, so can this now be reopened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you got the error message:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2800:3f0:4001:806::1005: Network is unreachable
```

... this has nothing to do with actually resolving IPv6 addresses. It would have returned a `host not found` or similar error if that was the case.

Without more information, to me the most likely explanations are:

1. Your computer does not have an IPv6 address. If you run `ifconfig` does your network adapter contain lines like the following:

   ```
     inet6 addr: fe80::922b:34ff:fe03:6d1a/64 Scope:Link
     inet6 addr: 1002:8bd:1000:efac::2/64 Scope:Global
   ```
2. Your ISP or their upstream providers cannot route IPv6 traffic.

Comment: i don't have a inet6 addr when i run ifconfig

Comment: Hey, i connected through my mobile on 3G and tried to do the same, and now some parts of it work! your on to the problem. But still, if they dont route ipv6, how come i can enter it through the browser?

Comment: Thank you, your input helped me a lot, it seems that my modem was in a buggy state, the ISP provider set its settings to factory defaults and updated it to a newer software. Now everything works fine.

Comment: You can certainly argue whether it's a bug to assume ipv6 should be working, but the upstream curl folks have recognised that there is a lot of broken ipv6 networking enabled on systems out there, and not falling back on ipv4 causes a lot of problems.  It's fixed upstream, but not in the versions packaged by ubuntu as of at least 14.04.